# Most efficient way of getting all combinations of two inputs, possibly with mapply R

Tags: r

Simplified example:
Lets say I have two arrays:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(2, 3, 4)
```

And i want to calculate the sum of both arrays for all combinations:

`mapply(sum, 1:3, 2:4)` will give me:
1+2; 2+3; 3+4

I am looking for

```
1+2; 1+3; 1+4;

2+2; 2+3; 3+4;

3+2; 3+3; 3+4;
```

Note: I am aware I can solve it with `for` loops or `combn`. But having 50.000+ arrays that will get very inefficient fast. Also note that `sum()` is just a sample function.

Comment: Look at `?outer` instead of `mapply`

Comment: what's the issue with using `combn`?

Comment: what about `expand.grid` or any of the more efficient versions of that on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well. `outer` takes all the combinations and you can specify to sum them.

```
outer(a,b,"+")
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    4    5
#> [2,]    4    5    6
#> [3,]    5    6    7
```

`expand.grid` will be slower but will create a two column data.frame that you can work on. Note, with `expand.grid` you can pass in any number of vectors, but the output will grow quickly. So, this won't work if you have a million things to cross with a million things (resulting in a trillion things). Also worth noting that this is a base function, but you could also try `tidyr::crossing(a,b)` or `data.table::CJ`  which could be faster (though not in this toy example).

```
df = expand.grid(a=a,b=b)
head(df)
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 2
#> 4 1 3
#> 5 2 3
#> 6 3 3
```

From this you can easily extract the sums.

```
r = df$a+df$b
r
#> [1] 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7
```